# How to change the background-color of the whole row when thead row has less columns than tbody rows?

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-table

I'm wondering how can I have the same width for all the rows in the table?
As you can see in the page...I want to change the background color of the header but the header doesnt have the same width as the  element in the body. 
How can I have  the same width for all the rows so the background color covers the whole width?
Thanks!

http://jsbin.com/ucafeh/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- the dark background has to cover the whole width of the second row...-->
       <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>hl</th>
                    <th>Invoice</th>
                    <th>fefe</th>
                    <th>fefefef</th>
                    <th>fe VAT</th>
                    <th>C. dfgdf VAT</th>
                    <th>dfgdf</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">17.17.17</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">50123</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">Invoice</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">Hola señor</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">-123.00</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">111</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">1200</a></th>
                <th><a class="inData" href="">GSP</a></th>
                <th><a class="deleteItem" href="#"><img src="" alt=""/>item</a></th>
                <th><a href="#myModal" role="" class="" data-toggle="modal">last-item</a></th>

            </tr>
```

Comment: You want to change the `color` of all cells *except* the last cell, or just have the `color` extend to the *end* of the last cell? And where is that empty space, following the last cell, coming from?

Comment: could you please show us the code for the whole table, including the existing CSS, preferably in a jsfiddle snippet ?

Comment: Is that red line something you drew in, or is that actually rendered in the page? If it's actually rendered in the page, please post a complete example with your CSS that we can use to reproduce this.

Comment: @j08691 I added a jsbin-file

Comment: By the way, in your tbody section you have th rather than td elements to contain your table values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you simply add 2 empty `th` elements before the closing `tr` tag inside `thead` (see this example: http://jsbin.com/iduxem/1)?

Then you could use the following simple CSS...

```
.table thead th { 
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Make the table span the whole width with `100%;`

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oliwiq/1/

Answer (score 0):

to color a row style the `<tr>` element with a background color

to expand the table to use all available width, style the `<table>` to be width:100% or fill the table with data and let it autosize itself

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your css was, but you can give your last TH a class and change the color.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasbrudy/sCmvj/

Or you can also use the last-child css selector.

```
th:last-child{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: hi Thomas I added a jsbinf-file so u understands what I mean...thanks.